# how can i verify that oracle database is installed in my linux machine? what would be the command for that?

Tags: linux

how can i verify that oracle database is installed in my linux machine? what would be the command for that?(Linux OS)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the location that you have installed the oracle application. What linux distribution are you using? What is the oracle version that you have installed on your machine? Maybe you can try to refer here :-
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/testing-oracle-10g-installation-on-red-hat-linux-as-40.html